# How to interop the library "libpython-clj2" with clojure in jupyter-notebook (clojupyter)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, clojure

Please comment how to interop the library "libpython-clj2" with clojupyter
When I execute these two commands in the notebook, I got errors.

```
(require '[libpython-clj2.python :as py :refer [py. py.. py.-]])
(require '[libpython-clj2.require :refer [require-python]])
```

Errors encountered after execute the require

```
Execution error (FileNotFoundException) at user/eval3658 (REPL:1).
Could not locate libpython_clj2/python__init.class, libpython_clj2/python.clj or libpython_clj2/python.cljc on classpath. Please check that namespaces with dashes use underscores in the Clojure file name.
Execution error (FileNotFoundException) at user/eval3660 (REPL:2).
Could not locate libpython_clj2/require__init.class, libpython_clj2/require.clj or libpython_clj2/require.cljc on classpath. Please check that namespaces with dashes use underscores in the Clojure file name.
```

Please feel free to comment.

Comment: The error seems to indicate that clojure cannot even find the main classes.  Do you still get the error with a bare REPL rather than clojupyter?

Comment: The library "libpython-clj2" can be imported with REPL (lein), but it cannot be imported with clojupyter.

Comment: Is it necessary to configure some setting in Clojupter? It is necessary to configure dependencies in project.clj with the new project is created with lein.

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar enough with clojupyter to help, but perhaps running both under conda will help.  https://github.com/clojupyter/clojupyter/blob/master/doc/usage-scenarios.md#conda-use-conda-to-install-clojupyter-on-linux-macos-and-windows  might be of use as well.

Comment: @madeinQuant, I think the problem is that you're using an incompatible version of `libpython-clj2`. I remember classes were not being found when I used a newer version. If you're following a tutorial, you might try finding a version of `libpython-clj2` that was last published prior to the date on which the tutorial was published. That way you're most likely using the same version as in the tutorial.